# How-to trigger ClipboardJS from jQuery contextMenu (2.x)

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, clipboard

I'm using jQuery contextMenu(2.x) and would like to copy to clipboard when pressing one menu item.
My problem is that I do not find a way to bind the click action from the contextmenu Item to clipboardJS (which I thought could be good to use here). So I don't know how to trigger the clipboard copy.

```
    jQuery.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    events: {

        show: function (options) {
            console.log('show Menu');
            //self.clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.li');         
        },
        hide: function (options) {
            console.log('hide Menu');
            //self.clipboard.destroy();          
        }
    },
    build: function ($trigger, e) {
        // this callback is executed every time the menu is to be shown
        // its results are destroyed every time the menu is hidden
        // e is the original contextmenu event, containing e.pageX and e.pageY (amongst other data)
        return {
            callback: function (key, options) {

                if (key === "item-one") {
                    alert('item-one');
                } else if (key === "copy") {
                    //COPY Text here
                }

            },
            items: {
                "item1": {
                    name: "item-one",
                    icon: "edit"
                },
                "copy": {
                    name: "copy",
                    icon: "fa-beer"
                },
                "sep1": "---------",
                "quit": {
                    name: "Quit",
                    icon: function ($element, key, item) {
                        return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.context-menu-one'); //HOW-TO TRIGGER?
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.info('Action:', e.action);
    console.info('Text:', e.text);
    console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error('Action:', e.action);
    console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
});
```

Would be great if someone has an idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two plugins that *may* be conflicting... But I found a work around.

First, define the Clipboard options like this (to avoid repeating):

```
var clipbardOptions = {
  target: function(trigger) {
    return trigger;
  }
};
```

I got inspired from [the documentation](https://clipboardjs.com/#advanced-usage) for the above...

Then, add this under your comment `//COPY Text here`.
It's only 3 lines added.
   *(I'm copying only the relevant part for clarity)*

```
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(e.target, clipbardOptions);
$(e.target).trigger("click");
clipboard.destroy();
```

The above is creating a Clipboard.js instance, triggers a click, so the plugin does its job... Then destroys the instance.

Demo in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bZoNzR?editors=0011).

---

Alternatively, in a **secure** page, you could simply forget about Clipboard.js and use:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText($(e.target).text());
```

[Why only in a secure page?](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi)

Comment: first solution is working fine for me. Thank you! The `navigator.clipboard` property is not available in Chrome on a non https page... (and that's actually what I'm having...)